# RESTful HTTP embedded hardware API - JSON field order significance

Tags: json, api, rest, hardware

I'm working on a RESTful HTTP API for an embedded hardware device.  In this API, hardware components are typically represented in a URI hierarchy of API Resources, which then have child JSON objects with attributes/fields specific to that hardware "object".  To control/modify the hardware, a HTTP PUT request is sent with a content-body of JSON object containing desired fields to be changed.

My question is about the order of fields within a JSON request body.  Let's say we are changing multiple fields in the same JSON object.  Since a JSON object is, [by definition](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), an "**unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs**", this implies that the order of applying those hardware changes is also unordered/undefined, which might not be good.

For example, what if "setting1" must be configured *before* "state" is set?  For example, the following might be sent as the content-body:

```
{
      "setting1": 1234,
      "state": "on",
}
```

But if we send the following instead, what happens?  (Notice the "state" field occurs first.)

```
{
      "state": "on",
      "setting1": 1234,
}
```

The problem is, by default the context of the JSON Object is "unordered", so the behavior is uncertain.

If it could be established (perhaps through API documentation) that the order of JSON fields in a request *is significant*, would this be considered a violation of best-practices in the context of JSON and RESTful APIs?  How have others dealt with this?  I would be surprised if this has not been discussed already, but I have not been able to find anything.

Comment: Could you please provide (even a fake) example?

Comment: Good suggestion Opal, thanks. I've edited the question with some clarifications and added an example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain, but I think that trying to impose an ordering restriction on clients is going to be problematic for some of them. I would bet that not all frameworks/JSON libraries will respect an ordering, at least not by default. If you control the client, this may not be a big deal, but it sounds like you don't.

Strictly speaking, you would have to send multiple PUT requests in order to ensure the updates happen in the correct order. That's the easiest to implement, but also the noisiest. Another option would be to instead support a PATCH call to the endpoint using the [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) format. That will let you control the order in which changes occur, but your clients need to build out PATCHes. You could also support a POST if neither of those appeal to you.